# octobercms .htaccess structure

Tags: php, .htaccess, octobercms

I need help with october cms .htaccess file. In my root, besides my website folders and files I have a folder which contains websites for some projects, 4 of them.

In my actual octobercms website i want to have 4 links to each website.

`projects/project-A`
`projects/project-B`
`projects/project-C`
`projects/project-D`

What must I do in my .htaccess file so I can open each website?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, Aram, but each of my 4 folders contain a website which i want to get linked to. I dont want to redirect to another website, but to run each website. hope i explained good enough :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `projects` folder is in `root` folder where you OctoberCMS resides, in short, where `index.php` and `.htaccess` file is.

Then you need to tell `apache` do not rewrite all request to `index.php` file when it sees `projects` in the begging of URL

add a rule to `.htaccess` file

```
##
## White listed folders
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/.well-known/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/uploads/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/media/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/temp/public/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/themes/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/plugins/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/modules/.*/(assets|resources)/.*

....
```

> Just add one more entry here like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/projects/*
```

It will allow you to server file from `projects` now and you can surf site from these folders.

The link will be like `https://october-plaza.com/projects/index.html` etc

I do not know much about `.htaccess` but I whitelist folders like this so I can access files from it

if any doubts please comment.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this well hetp you

`Redirect /projects/project-A/ http://www.example.com/private/`

Comment: Thank you, Aram, but each of my 4 folders contain a website which i want to get linked to. I dont want to redirect to another website, but to run each website. hope i explained good enough :)

Comment: OK then sorry that I diid not answered on your question